# One Contact Receiving My Messages Under An Email, Not My Contact Name

Tags: iphone, ios, email, messages, contacts

My iMessage is working with all iPhone users, except with a specific contact. iMessage is working with this contact, except that he is only able to receive my iMessages as my email address and not from my phone number. I use my email as my ID for both iPad and iPhone. I have my send & receive settings set to only my phone number, so when i try to send an iMessage to this contact, it automatically fails to deliver. Anything i can do about it? Is it something to do with his settings or mine?

Answer (score 1):

iMessage can be configured to send/receive from your phone number as well as any email addresses that you have verified through your account. If your iPhone is configured to start new conversations from your phone number, but continues sending from your email address to a particular contact, you would need to delete the existing conversation with that contact and start a new one.